# problem with function named create in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

i have a base class declarated like this

```
type
  TBaseClass=class
   protected
    constructor Create(LoadData:boolean;const Param1,Param2:string); overload;
   public
    Destructor  Destroy; override;
  end;
```

Now in another unit a child class `TChid_Class` which descend from  `TBaseClass`

```
  TChid_Class=class(TBaseClass)
   function Create(const Param1, Param2 : String;const Param3 : OleVariant ; var Param4 : LongInt): Integer;overload;
   constructor Create; overload;
   constructor Create(LoadData:boolean); overload;
  end;
```

in this class exist a function called `Create` like the constructors, the problem is , when i try to create a instance to the `TChid_Class` i have an access violation.

i wrote this small console app which show the problem

```
program TestClass;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Variants,
  SysUtils;

type
  TBaseClass=class
   protected
    constructor Create(LoadData:boolean;const Param1,Param2:string); overload;
   public
    Destructor  Destroy; override;
  end;

  TChid_Class=class(TBaseClass)
   function Create(const Param1, Param2 : String;const Param3 : OleVariant ; var Param4 : LongInt): Integer;overload;
   constructor Create; overload;
   constructor Create(LoadData:boolean); overload;
  end;

{ TBaseClass }

constructor TBaseClass.Create(LoadData: boolean; const Param1, Param2: string);
begin
   inherited Create;
   Writeln('constructor TBaseClass.Create(LoadData: boolean; const Param1, Param2: string);');
end;

destructor TBaseClass.Destroy;
begin
   //Code
  inherited;
end;

{ TChid_Class }

function TChid_Class.Create(const Param1, Param2: String;  const Param3: OleVariant; var Param4: Integer): Integer;
begin
   Writeln('function create');
   Result:=0;
end;

constructor TChid_Class.Create;
begin
   Writeln('constructor TChid_Class.Create');
   Create(True);
end;

constructor TChid_Class.Create(LoadData: boolean);
begin
  Writeln('constructor TChid_Class.Create(LoadData: boolean)'); //here is the access violation
  Create(LoadData,'Value 1','Value 2');
end;


var
   Invoker : TChid_Class;
   Pid     : integer;
begin
  try
     Invoker:=TChid_Class.Create;
     try
       Invoker.Create('','',Unassigned,Pid)
     finally
      Invoker.Free;
     end;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

  readln;
end.
```

if i rename the function create, the problem is go away, but i am looking for a solution without rename the create function or the constructors.

using delphi 2007

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get an access violation when I run this under Delphi 2010.  What version are you using?

Comment: @Mason - I get the AV with D2007. @Salvador - Moving the function to after the constructors seems to avoid the AV.

Comment: Of course I meant the function declaration.

Comment: @sertac, thanks i checked in delphi 5  and the AV occurs as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Delphi 7 I get an AV too. Renaming the method or moving it (as suggested by Sertac Akyuz) fixes the AV.

What I discovered by looking at the assembler:

When creating a new object a non-zero value is placed in register `dl` before calling the constructor.

```
mov dl,$01              // dl set to 1
mov eax,[$00401268]
call TChild_Class.Create
```

Then in the constructor, on the `begin` line, ClassCreate is called when `dl` is non-zero.

```
test dl,dl       
jz +$08          //if dl = 0 then do not call ClassCreate
add esp,-$10
call -$00000396  //calls ClassCreate
```

But then it goes wrong, with your code, the compiler sets `dl` to 1 again before calling `Create(True)`, so on the `begin` line of `TChid_Class.Create(LoadData: boolean);`, ClassCreate is called again which results in an AV.

After renaming your function or moving its declaration, the compiler clears `dl` (`xor edx,edx`) instead of setting it to 1, before calling `Create(True)`.

My guess is that it is a bug in the Delphi compiler which is fixed in Delphi 2010 and higher.

Comment: Very close, but when I have checked with debbuger the **dl** reference counter is always 1, but VMT (Virtual method table) address in **eax** is wrong in second constructor when is calling TObject.NewInstance!

Comment: @GJ: Either way, I think it is a bug in the Delphi compiler, not the code.

Answer (score 2):

*Partial answer*: In your constructor TChid_Class.Create(LoadData: boolean) you are missing **'inherited'** in your Create call.  This fixes an AV in the example code if you call *TChid_Class.Create(True)* in your demo project.

```
constructor TChid_Class.Create(LoadData: boolean);
begin
  Writeln('constructor TChid_Class.Create(LoadData: boolean)'); //here is the access violation
  inherited Create(LoadData,'Value 1','Value 2'); //add "INHERITED"
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried  your suggestion but the AV continues, do you try this in delphi 2007?

Comment: did you add inherited to all the TChid_Class.Create ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong way to create object! You can't call more than one constructor in **one** class at creation, but you can **only inherite creation**.
So the right way is something like:

```
constructor TChid_Class.Create(LoadData: boolean = True);
begin
  Writeln('constructor TChid_Class.Create(LoadData: boolean)'); //here is the access violation
  inherited Create(LoadData,'Value 1','Value 2');
end;
```

Reserved word **inherited** tell to the parent constructor that object is created in child class constructor.
Checked under D2007!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with calling multiple constructors from the same class.

Comment: @The_Fox: Yes it is! You can't call more than one constructor in the same class, but you can only inherite it from parent class! Because when you calling the second constructor in the some class the TObject.NewInstance will be called again and this will raise an exception! I have checked this error with debbuger under D2007.

Comment: Then it is probably a bug (see my answer), because there is nothing wrong with having multiple overloaded constructors that all call one constructor with default settings. Just like Salvador did.

Comment: Yes, tested under D2010 works OK! This exception is well known. So they have impruved the Delphi compiler

Comment: I agree, it is just wrong to call a second constructor that is not inherited.

Answer (score 0):

This was a compiler bug until the last updates of Delphi 2007.
It works from Delphi 2009 and up.

Renaming the `Create` function to `Initialize` solves your problem. It is not only a workaround, 
but is both correct for fixing the bug, and from a coding perspective:
As a general rule, there should be a clear distinction in the construction and initialization of object instances.

- Construction should be short, and not raise exceptions.
- Initialization can take longer and might raise an exception.

--jeroen